# Error when checking which Rails Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try the "rails -v" command in Terminal, I get the following error: `bin/rails:4:in require: cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from bin/rails:4:in <main>'`                                                                              I was/am having trouble getting rails server to start, so I attempted to check my version. Does anyone have any idea what this means?  I'm on Mac osx 10.7.5 and ruby 2.0. I know I had Rails 4.0.2 installed, but don't know what this means. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like you're trying to run command within a rails application and since you may have upgraded to rails 4.x, which seeks bin/rails dir in application(which doesn't exists because the app is on old rails version). So, try: `bundle exec rails --version`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: That actually gives the same error I get when trying to run the rails server:  `/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:240:in `block in replace_gem': railties is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)`

Comment: I've added railties to my gemfile, then did "bundle install" and I get: `The Gemfile specifies no dependencies
Your bundle is complete!`

Comment: Remove railties, it is not needed. It comes with rails itself.

Comment: Why would it be saying to add railties to the gemfile though?

Comment: My bad!! I just took this into a wrong direction. I am sorry. What you need is the rails 4.x version for your application. Just to see if the issue still persists. open: `bin/rails` file and comment line number 4. And then please let me know what happens. By the way, which version of rails is mentioned in your app's Gemfile?

Comment: Ok, So I commented that out, then I try "rails server" command, and nothing happens at all. No error though.

Comment: The gemfile in my project folder is blank, but the gemfile.LOCAL shows my gems and includes `gem 'rails', '4.0.2'`

Comment: @Surya Yea, so no rails commands do anything at all. I'm assuming it's because we commented that line out, right?

Comment: Yes, that's because you have commented out the line number 4. Now, open app's Gemfile, and add: gem 'rails', '4.0.2', run: `bundle install`, then try your commands? Please remember to uncomment that line before running commands as well.

Comment: YES! That did it! Thank you so much! I'm sure you're busy, but if you have time later, can you please help me wrap my head around what we did. Why was the main gemfile empty, but the gemfile.LOCAL had all the gems listed inside it? Also, did you want to add that last reply as an answer so I can accept yours?

Comment: I did. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>First of all, uninstall rails 4.x versions:</strike>

<strike>`gem uninstall rails`</strike>

Here, uninstall all rails version starts with 4.x etc.

And then try running the same commands(<strike>without running</strike> `gem install rails`):

```
$ rails s
# rails version:
$ rails --verison
```

**UPDATE:**

Open app's **Gemfile**, and add this line:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

Now run:

```
bundle install
```

Since, there was no rails gem mentioned in your Gemfile, when you ran rails commands they couldn't find the reference/relate to the rails version you were referring to. I don't know why Gemfile was empty, but Gemfile.lock. Gemfile.lock is created after you run `bundle install` or `bundle update`, which denotes the locked version of gems to be used in your application. So, maybe something wrong happened with your Gemfile and not to Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 1):

First go on your application like cd myproject and than try rails -v. if it not work than you should not install rails on your gemset. So you need to install rails on your gemset. using

```
gem install rails
```

and than it work.

Comment: When I do that command, I get: `Successfully installed rails-4.0.2
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.2` but then I try "rails server" again, and I get the same original error. I just don't get it!

Comment: Currently you have rails-4.0.2 in your system, Check whether your application contains the same version if not install rails version which is present in your application (eg. gem install rails -v 3.0.1)

Comment: When I'm inside my project's directory, and I try to check the version of Rails, I get the error still.